# How to copy files from HDFS to remote HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to copy files from my Hadoop cluster to the remote cluster.

I have the hadoop_conf file in the remote cluster and can access it by setting `HADOOP_CONF_DIR.`

I know the IP and port of the remote name node.

I want to copy the file through the namespace as ex below.

> ex) hadoop fs -cp hdfs://MyNamespace/path/file hdfs://RemoteNamespace/path/file

However, if I do not configure `hadoop_conf_dir`, I do not know the remote namespace, and if I set the information of remote cluster in `hadoop_conf_dir`, I can not access my cluster's namespace.

Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to copy between clusters is using `distcp`.

```
$ hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/foo/bar hdfs://nn2:8020/bar/foo
```

See 
[DistCp Version2 Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) for more information.

Comment: I know how to use the dispcp command.
My question is, I want to use namespace to communicate between different clusters.
Is there only one way to hard-code the address of the name node in one of the two clusters?

Comment: If your setup is `federated` then using namespace would work.  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html

Comment: I think federation only exists in recent releases of Hadoop

Comment: @lucas, what version of Hadoop are you running?